# No zeroes or blank in fields

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule, isblank

I want that when they user move to Stage 1, they have to enter an amount for the MRR and ARR greater than zero(0) and not to leave it blank. I created this  validation rule and even if I input an amount greater than zero the error message stills comes up. What am I doing wrong?

```
AND(
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "1 - Qualify"),
        (ARR__c != 0), 
        (MRR__c != 0)
    )
)
```

Comment: Quick note: Good practice is to indent formulas and to keep separate conceptual "units" on separate lines. It helps make things easier to read (especially if you have a sea of parenthesis). I've done this formatting for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

You have written formula such that if any of the condition satisfies it should throw the validation rule.

I guess the validation should thrown error only when `StageName = '1 - Qualify' AND (ARR__c!= 0 or MRR__c!=0)` which means the `OR()` condition should be only for ARR__c and  MRR__c fields and AND condition for stagename and `OR()`.

Also as you mentioned the fields should not be Null so you have to use `ISBLANK(fieldName)`.

The formula should be as below.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "1 - Qualify"), TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName)) != '1 - Qualify' , OR(ARR__c <= 0,MRR__c <= 0))
```

I have added `PRIORVALUE(StageName)` because this validation should fire only when the stage is changed to "1 - Qualify" If that is  not the case you can remove that condition.

Comment: thank you SaiPraveen Kakkirala it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

2 main notes here:

- Validation rules trigger when the result of the formula is `true`, so you need to shift your thinking to "what does *invalid* data look like?" (as opposed to what I think is the more natural approach of "what does valid data look like?")
- Right now, you're tossing everything into the `OR()` function, and there is nothing being `AND()`ed together (it evaluates to `AND(true)` or `AND(false)`). `AND()` and `OR()` with a single value are not very useful

Your current validation rule doesn't behave correctly because if StageName = 1  - Qualify (or if ARR/MRR are non-zero) it causes the entire `OR()` to be true, which causes the `AND()` to be true.

A good way to start writing a validation rule is to lay it out in mostly plain language (but still trying to structure it in a way that is close to how you think a formula would end up looking). In this case...

My record is invalid when:

- StageName is "1 - Qualify"
- and either ARR or MRR is 0 (or less)

It shouldn't be too much of a stretch to see that this should become

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(StageName, "1 - Qualify"),
    OR(
        ARR__c <= 0,
        MRR__c <= 0
    )
)
```

This assumes that your formula is set to "treat blanks as zeros". Setting your formula to "treat blanks as blanks" would make things more complicated.